# Circular import of numpy error in the scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science

Even during the build of the sklearn, at the end it showing a message like Partial import of sklearn during the build process, though it's successfully installed the scikit-learn

When i tried to run python file which import numpy, it's throwing an circular import(while i run the python file in utils folder of sklearn), while outside it's running fine.

*build*
[image: build]

*Numpy circular import error*
[image: Numpy circular import error]

please ignore drive (i.e f and d in the screenshot), while taking screenshot i took it differently. i have the something in the f and d drive.

Comment: What is exp.py? where is it present? I cannot find it on github. Please post the contents of exp.py

Comment: it's my own file. i just added it over there for debuging. when i try to run exp.py which contains import numpy, it's throwing me the circular import error.(exp.py is inside the utils folder of sklearn)